# Can anyone help me with node.js, database querying with a search box

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, database

So I am creating a web app for a calorie counter appl, the page im stuck on currently is a search food page, so the user types in the food in the search bar, if its in the database ive created it will show the food and all its nutrition,

Now this all works fine, however if the user types in a food which is not in the database or which is spelt incorrectly, it is supposed to be showing a message on screen stating so.

This is my main.js file

```
app.get("/search-result", function (req, res) {
    //searching in the database
       let word = [`%${req.query.name}%`];
       let sqlquery = `SELECT * FROM food WHERE name LIKE '%${req.query.name}%'`;
       db.query(sqlquery, (err, result) => {
           if (err)  {
                return console.error('There is no food with that name' + req.query.name);
            }else{
                res.render('ListFood.html', {availableFood: result});
               }
           });
       });
```

This is my index.js file

```
const express = require ("express");
const bodyParser = require ("body-parser");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const port = 8089;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const db = mysql.createConnection ({
 host: "localhost",
 user: "root",
 password: "root",
 database: "foodList" });
// connect to database
db.connect((err) => {
 if (err) {
 throw err;
 }
 console.log("Connected to database");
});
global.db = db;
require("./routes/main")(app);
app.set("views",__dirname + "/views");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.engine("html", require("ejs").renderFile);
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

This is my search food.html view file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Search</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1> Food Search page </h1>
 <p>In the box below please type in the name of the food you would like to search for in our database. If the food is in the database it will show you the nutritonal values, if it is not in our database and you would like to add it in, please visit the Add Food page.</p>
 <form action="/topic7/mid-term/search-result/" method="GET">
 <input id="search-box" type="text" name="name" value="Food Name">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
 </form>
 <br>
     <a href="/topic7/mid-term/"><strong>HOME</strong></a>
 <br>
 </body>
</html>
```

And finally this is my list food.html, this is the page it shows when the food is correct, but seems to get stuck reading the title and header even when the food is not in the database

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>List webpage!</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1> Food List </h1>
 <h3>You can see names and nutritional values of different food here:</h3>
 <ul>
 <% availableFood.forEach(function(food){ %>
 <li><%= food.name %>, Typical Value: <%= food.typicalvalues %>, Unit of typical value: <%= food.Unitofthetypicalvalue %>, calories: <%= food.calories %>, carbs: <%= food.carbs %>, fat: <%= food.fat %>, protein: <%= food.protein %>, salt: <%= food.salt %>, sugar: <%= food.sugar %></li>
 <% }) %>
 </ul>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Ive been looking at this for hours and just cant seem to figure out why.
I am very new to this so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the query function only returns an error if there was an actual error querying the database and not if no element was found. Even if no element was found, the function will hand your callback a results object. I am unsure of the structure of that object though, but with a bit of console logging you should be able to find out where to find the number of elements returned from the query.

Comment: Strange, Ive looked at code which others have done as this is a group project, and my code is very much similar to theirs using query, theirs seems to work whereas mine does not frustratingly.

Comment: In this case, I really don't think that is the way to go. The function only returns an error if it actually encounters one while connecting or querying. If the server replies with an empty set of results, that is not an error, it is a result. The answer from @Danizavtz looks pretty good btw.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at zero length results to show proper not found error message.

```
(err, result) => {
    if (err)  {
        console.error('Database error in query data');
        res.render('500.html')
        return
    }
    if (result.length === 0) {
        //show not found error
        console.error('There is no food with that name' + req.query.name);
        res.render('ListFoodEmpty.html')
    }else{
        res.render('ListFood.html', {availableFood: result});
    }
});
```

### Some options to follow

In my example I used a `'ListFoodEmpty.html'` as a parameter in render function. If you choose that way, you have to implement a default html template for handle not found results.

Or you can reuse your `ListFood.html` template and check zero-length array before running the `forEach`, and put a proper error message for not found results.
If you choose this way, you can left your route `/search-result` as is and change the `ListFood.html` template.

I too would like to point out that if you are not validating your strings before running a query against database, you are open to [sql injection atacks](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection). You must use prepared statements offered by database lib, and sanitize and validate input before running.